# Missing Namespace Assistance

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, ssis

I can't find the following namespace on any of my dev boxes

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
```

I have Visual Studio Team System 2008 on some machines and Visual Studio 2005 on some. What do I need to install to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS assembly and inside  microsoft.sqlserver.manageddts.dll, it can be probably be found at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies

It should be deployed with your SQL Server installation (you need to install the SDK portion of it).

Comment: Indeed, I added a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS and I am able to see the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the types in this namespace are from the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS assembly.  This is installed with SQL Server.

It sounds like SQL Server is not installed on this machine.  Install a local copy, and it should find the assembly correctly.

Comment: you are saying that I need to install SQL Server on my dev boxes? Can't SQL Express do?

Comment: You need to have the integration services installed:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx   This installs with the full version of SQL Server, but I don't believe it does with express.  VS tries to install a dev version of SQL server - which you must have turned off with your VS installations.

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx), which is a part of the SQL Server setup. For information about which editions that support this, see [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx).